# Android LinearProgressIndicator "updateSurface: has no frame"

Tags: android, linearprogressindicator

in a constraint layout I show a progress bar as shown below.

```
        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
            android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            app:indeterminateAnimationType="disjoint"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/primaryLightColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loadingBarText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:trackColor="@color/primaryColor"
            app:trackThickness="4dp" />
```

The progress bar is indeterminate and it is displayed correctly by the app,therefore there are no problems regarding the user experience.

however in the Logcat this log is printed every millisecond: **updateSurface: has no frame**

The message is printed by this [android class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java).

The message disappears if I remove the **indeterminate** property and is printed only if the app is installed in debug, therefore it does not foresee problems in production.

But I wanted to understand what is the cause and if there is a solution to avoid this log message.